# Cleaning up Compiler class

Tags: c#, parsing

What is the best way to considerably decrease the size of the following code without sacrificing functionality, and to make it more readable, and well, make it look professional?

```
class Compiler
{        
    public string Compile(TextReader src)
    {
        string rtn = SourceTemplate.Top;

        var preprocessor = new PreProcessor();

        Parser[] ParserRounds = {
                                    new PredefinedConstantParser(),
                                    new VariableDeclarationParser(), 
                                    new ConditionalExpressionParser(),
                                    new FunctionCallParser()//,
                                  //new FunctionParser
                                };

        foreach (var l in preprocessor.Process(src))
        {
            var line = l;

            foreach (var parser in ParserRounds)
            {
                line = parser.Parse(line);
            }

            rtn += "\t\t\t" + line + "\n";
        }

        return rtn + SourceTemplate.Bottom;
    }

    public static void Start(string[] args)
    {
        TextReader src = File.OpenText(args[0]);      

        var com = new Compiler();
        var source = com.Compile(src);

        string target = args[0].TrimEnd(".hack".ToCharArray());
        target += ".cs";                     
    }

    public void SaveToFile(string source, string target)
    {
        TextWriter wsrc = File.CreateText(target);
        wsrc.WriteLine(source);
        wsrc.Close();
    }
}
```

In my personal opinion, the above code looks like a mess at this stage. Also, please suggest good and expressive variable names instead of `rtn` , `src` etc.  Should I also make this class generic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just some generic notes since I'm not too familiar with C#:

1. [`rtn` should be `StringBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)
2. I'd change the `preprocessor` and `ParserRounds` variables to fields and pass their values to the constructor of the class. It makes testing easier (you can test only one parser at a time, you can test with a mocked preprocessor etc.) and it results looser coupling.
3. Using `SourceTemplate.Top` and `SourceTemplate.Bottom` also tight coupling, pass these values to the constructor too, store them in a field and use these fields in the `Compile` method. (Maybe it's worth creating a `SourceTemplate` interface with `GetTop()` and `GetBottom()` methods and passing a proper instance to the `Compiler` class.)
4. I'm really missing the input validation. For example, if the `Compile` method get a `null` as a value of `TextReader` you should throw an exception immediately. It helps debugging a lot. Why would you do any compiling if it will throw an exception later since the `TextReader` is `null`?

   The `Start` method also should check the input values.
5. Some variable naming ideas:

   - `src` -> `sourceReader` or `srcReader`
   - `com` -> `compiler`
   - `target` -> `targetFileName`
   - `rtn` -> `result`
   - `wsrc` -> `targetWriter`

Answer (score 2):

Building on the great answers provided by @palacsint and @toto2 I have put together a quick sample of what could be done to improve your application.

For me code speaks louder than words so here goes:

```
// SOLID: Interface Segregation Principle
//        Use an interface to allow better / easier unit testing 
//        through mocking.
    internal interface ICompiler
{
    string Compile(string textFileContents);
}

// SOLID: Interface Segregation Principle
//        Once again using an interface will allow the preprocessor 
//        to be mocked in unit testing.
interface ITextPreProcessor
{
    IEnumerable<string> Process(string lines);
}

// SOLID: Interface Segregation Principle
//        Use an interface to allow better / easier unit testing 
//        through mocking.
internal interface ITextParser
{
    string Parse(string line);
}

// SOLID: Single Responsibility Principle
//        This class is responsible for the parsing of text files.
//        The class is NOT responsible for loading or pesisting the
//        parsed response.
internal class Compiler : ICompiler
{
    public Compiler()
        : this(new PreProcessor())
    { }

    // other text parsers have been omitted from this code sample
    public Compiler(ITextPreProcessor textPreProcessor)
        : this(textPreProcessor, new ITextParser[] { new PredefinedConstantParser(), new VariableDeclarationParser() }
            )
    { }

    // using this constructor allows for better object mocking and unit testing.
    public Compiler(ITextPreProcessor textPreProcessor, IEnumerable<ITextParser> parserRounds)
    {
        // depending on your business logic you may want to check for null value objects 
        // and throw an exception here
        if (textPreProcessor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("textPreProcessor");
        if (parserRounds == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("parserRounds");

        TextPreProcessor = textPreProcessor;
        ParserRounds = parserRounds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the text pre processor.
    /// </summary>
    public ITextPreProcessor TextPreProcessor { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the parser rounds.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<ITextParser> ParserRounds { get; private set; }

    public string Compile(string textFileContents)
    {
        // depending on your business rules you may want to throw an
        // exception if the textFileContents variable is null???
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textFileContents)) throw new ArgumentNullException("textFileContents");

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine(SourceTemplate.Top);
        builder.AppendLine("\t\t\t");

        foreach (var line in TextPreProcessor.Process(textFileContents))
        {
            foreach (var parser in ParserRounds)
            {
                // depending on your business rules you may want to either use a 
                // try catch exception block here if the returnv value from "Parse"
                // is null or empty by letting the exceptions bubble up
                // to the layer responsible for doing something with the exception???
                builder.AppendLine(parser.Parse(line));
            }

            builder.AppendLine("\n");
        }

        builder.AppendLine(SourceTemplate.Bottom);
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

// SOLID: This class is responsible for the management
public class ParseManager
{
    public static void Start(string[] args)
    {
        var sourceFileContents = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);

        try
        {
            ICompiler compiler = new Compiler();
            var parsedContents = compiler.Compile(sourceFileContents);

            string destinationPath = string.Format("{0}.cs", args[0].TrimEnd(".hack".ToCharArray()));

            // writing text files can be done in 1 line so there
            // is no need to wrap this in a seperate method
            File.WriteAllText(destinationPath, parsedContents);

            // sample 
            Console.WriteLine("Parsed file saved: {0}", destinationPath);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Below are some sample class implementations to show how this improvement could be used

```
// sample class implementation
internal class PreProcessor : ITextPreProcessor
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Process(string lines)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// sample parser implementation
internal class PredefinedConstantParser : ITextParser
{
    public string Parse(string line)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

// sample parser implementation
internal class VariableDeclarationParser : ITextParser
{
    public string Parse(string line)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

With naming standards I tend to use those offered by [IDesign](http://idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20CSharp%20Coding%20Standard.zip) as they take out any personal preference and are in line with best practice suggested by Microsoft.

For details on the SOLID principles refer to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [here](http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/SOLID%20Principle). IMHO SOLID is one of the most important aspects in writing good software applications.

Answer (score 1):

`ParserRounds` should not start with a capital since it is an instance.

But much worse is that it should not exist at all: you are straying very far from OO. Instead of the for-loop that calls the members of parserRounds you should think of some OO pattern to use, where the `line` goes through some "automatic" chain of processing. There are probably many different ways to proceed, but I can think of passing the line to some instance of `Parser` that itself contains the other subclasses of `Parser` in order.